# In mini-ninja how do you fish?

Tags: pc, mini-ninjas

I'm playing mini-ninja on my pc. I was sailing on the ninja hat boat and successfully caught my first fish. However, when I tried catching again I am unable to do so.

when I'm trying to fish again he just puts out the rod as if he is fishing and waits but there is no bait on the rod. So the fish don't come. Any idea how to fish again? Do we need to find bait again or what? Or is it that he won't bait as long as he has "1 sushi" in his inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have found out why he was not tossing the fishing line. Basically, you press "F" for throwing the fishing line and he throws it. But when he doesn't throw it you need to keep "F" pressed. This brings up the aiming reticule and only then (on releasing "F") does he throw the fishing line.

The trick is to keep "F" key pressed.

Comment: That's quite a trick!